# Post form-data request in Kotlin retrofit Android

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I need to send a form-data request, where there is a photo (file, which is a maximum of 5) and description and longitude, latitude fields (which are a maximum of 5).

When I send it as a normal request, it complains saying json/application not found, like so I sent this request, but I think it’s wrong:

```
data class(val desc:String, val latitude: List<String>, ... val image  : List<MultipartBody.Part>)
```